# How to split string by '/' in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, split, stl

I have unordered_set of strings.

And, on input i get a file.
For example, this kind of strings.

"AA/BB/CC"

"YY/XX"

"BB/DD/LL"

I want to see in my set this:

AA

AA/BB

AA/BB/CC

BB

BB/DD

BB/DD/LL

YY

YY/XX

```
std::string instances_file { "/home/areg/Desktop/instance_file.txt" };
std::string str { "\n\t\r" };
char delimiter {'/'};
std::ifstream ifs (instances_file);

while(std::getline(ifs, str, delimiter))
     unoset.insert(str);
```

Can you please provide a STL algorithm for doing this, or help me with the code?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and ask for help with a solution. Most people frown on doing somebody else's work, but are here to help.

Comment: Many examples of how to split a string here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: Your first problem is understanding what you want to do.  Then you need to describe it.  Neither is clear.  A [mcve] with details about what is going wrong, what the output is, and what you would want the output to be is often useful.